# Update model value on object with unknown name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I've got a following template:

```
<select 
    id="someSelect"
    ng-model="component.picture" 
    ng-controller="someChildController" 
    size="12"
    ng-options="img.url as img.name for img in image.list | filter:img.filter">
</select>
```

The important part is *ng-model*. I want to make the code as re-usable as possible, so consider this model as one that could change anytime. The question is, how to change the value from the controller, when I cannot update $scope.component.picture directly?

Is there some way to get element's model object, no matter what is it's object name?

**EDIT:**

I may have not been clear. Consider the case, where in different place in the application the same template is used, but with changed model (so, no *component.picture*). But it's still wrapped in child controller which handles the updates of the model. I cannot call *component.picture* directly, because I cannot be sure it's the one in *ng-model*.

If everything else fail, I may need to do something like:

```
var _el = angular.element('#someSelect');
var path = _el.attr('ng-model').split('.');
var model = $scope;
var lastIndex = -1;

path.forEach(function(p, i) {
    if(typeof model[p] === 'object') {
        model = model[p];
        lastIndex = i;
    }
    else return false;
});

model[path[lastIndex+1]] = "someNewValue";
```

But it's quite ugly, so I wanted to know, if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Use a directive with specific scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a directive you can inject any kind of scope objects, doesn't matter what the namespaces are, the directive will take that data as "thisdata" creating a new specific scope it can use to display the HTML starting from the template provided.

```
// HTML
<test-dir component="component.picture" images="image.list"></test-dir>

// JS
app.directive('testDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { component: '=', images: '=' },
        template: '<select size="12" ng-options="img.url as img.name for img in images | filter:img.filter"></select>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.component);
            console.log(scope.images);
        }
    }
})
```

I didn't test it!

Comment: Isn't the scope here isolated? There wouldn't be access to image.list array. And what's more, it doesn't use **ng-model** at all.
I guess you confused the model with source array.

Comment: You don't need ng-model, you are using an isolated scope in a directive you can reuse everywhere. For example you can add another element like this: `<test-dir component="anothercomponent.anotherpicture" images="anotherimage.anotherlist"></test-dir>` - Code edited

Answer (score 0):

You could use a directive with a template where you pass the list of elements and the model such as:

```
app.directive("newDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            image: '=',
            component: '='
        },
        template: '<select ng-model = "component" size = "12" ng-options = "img.url as img.name for img in image.list | filter:img.filter" > </select>'

    }
});
```

Here the html is stored into the template which is applied every time the directive is called and it's creating a scope for the variables:

- the `ngModel`
- the object containing the list of rendered options

In this way you can a new model every time you need it with:

```
<new-directive image="img" component="comp.picture"></new-directive>
```

Where `img` is the object containing the list in your controller and `comp` is the variable where the value is stored.

I created a jsfiddle that may help you.

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/vaebkkg9/2/

**EDIT**: I changed the code so you just use `component` and not `component.picture`. If you want to assign a property of an object you have just to use it as `component="comp.picture"`

Comment: What I want to accomplish is reusability. That excludes adding specific namespace to the directive (here - **component.picture** is still there).

Comment: **component.picture**  is not there anymore